# Connecting two virtual machines together

Tags: 14.04, networking

I have three virtual machines set up. A router, client and server all on Ubuntu. I can ping from the router to both client and server. I can ping from the server to both ports on the router and same with the client. However, I can't ping from server to client or client to server.

Answer (score 1):

you need to enable packet forwarding on your router:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```